# Taking care of mint with bent stems

Tags: mint

A few of my mint plant's stems are bent, some by almost 90 degrees (this isn't from disease, it came about as a result of rough treatment). I tried bending the stems back, but they go back to being bent in a few seconds. Should I leave the plant be and allow it to heal? Or is this a more serious condition, and should I cut off the stem below the bend with a scissor?

Comment: Pictures, please?

Comment: Is it in a pot or in the ground? And as requested, yes, photo please

Answer (score 2):

Most of the mint plant will recover.

Strong wind and footfall is common, so they are evolved to recover. It will take few days.